# If $\sum^\infty_{n = 1} {x_n}^2$ converges, does $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{x_n}{n} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think it is true since $x_n$ has to be at least order $1/n$ for $\sum^\infty_{n = 1} {x_n}^2$ to converge. But how would I write a proof?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $ab\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe by Cauchy Schwarz
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{x_n}{n}\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2}.
\end{align}